# Rails JSON injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In Rails 2.3 I always used

```
render :json => { :success => true, :data => @foobar}
```

to send JSON data to my frontend. In Rails 3 I'm using

```
respond_to :json
...
respond_with @foobar
```

But what I'm missing: I need the 'success' value within the JSON structure. What's the right way to inject such data into JSON response in Rails 3?

---

Hm, tried this too, but I get the following error as result:

```
SyntaxError (app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
respond_with { :success => true, :data => @property }
                          ^
/app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:13: Can't assign to true
respond_with { :success => true, :data => @property }
                                ^
app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
respond_with { :success => true, :data => @property }
```

Answer (score 4):

When things doesn't fit the default, you need to go back to the previous customized way.
`respond_with` accepts a block.

```
respond_with @foobar do |format|
  format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :data => @foobar} }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the object like value. You just add some key/value inside with override `serializable_hash` method

But you can generate your hash in respond_with

```
respond_with { :success => true, :data => @foobar}
```

Comment: Hmhm, tried this too, but I get the following error as result: